# Docker run inside a container

Tags: python, docker

I have a Python method code using docker and I try to understand it. The method is here,

```
def exec(self, container_target, command, additional_options=""):
    """ execte docker exec commmand and return the stdout or None when error"""
    cmd = """docker exec -i "%s" sh -c '%s' %s""" % (
        container_target, command, additional_options)
    if self.verbose:
        print(cmd)
    try:
        cp = subprocess.run(cmd,
                            shell=True,
                            check=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return cp.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Docker exec failed command {e}")
        return None
```

I get the screenshot at the time of debugging,

[image]

The `cmd` value is found,

> 'docker exec -i "craft_p2-2" sh -c \'cd craft && composer show
>   --name-only | grep nerds-and-company/schematic | wc -l\' '

My understanding is the code using the shell of the container named `craft_p2-2` and enters a folder named `craft`. Then, it checks if the `Schematic` plugin is installed. Is that correct?

This might be obvious for some, but, I don't come with a wealth of container knowledge and need to be sure of what's going on.

Comment: It seems correct, this is quit basic to docker, please read here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: You should be aware that code has massive security issues, and can be easily used to take complete control over the physical machine it runs on.  (Consider what happens if `container_target` begins with `"; docker run`.)  This code also is intrinsically trusted with root-level access over the host, security issues or otherwise.  I wouldn't recommend this as a way of interacting with containers.

Comment: What would you suggest then? At the time we use personally to create a few Php projects, but, in the future, we have the plan to provide the service to the other people as well.